# what is the scope of Viewbag in mvc3 and how do we maintain state in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

1. what is the scope of Viewbag in mvc3 is it only available on the page we are rendering through my action method.
2. How do we maintain information across the  page in MVC. Suppose i Create new employee and and when I move to next page I want that employee information.
3. How do we maintain state in MVC.

Comment: I would also add try to avoid using ViewBag unless you have to because you can't then use the generic helper methods like EditorFor<t>, if you need a mix of data from different models on your page create a ViewModel that has everything you need, it make life much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. the view bag is part of the httpcontext. it's primarily set in the controller action and  read in the view, but it can be accessed from just about anywhere in the mvc framework within an http request/response.
2. the web does not have state, like you would in a rich client app. To maintain values from page to page (or more appropriately, request to request) you can use cookies, session, query string, the request body (think post/put requests).
3. same as #2.

Answer (score 1):

1. `ViewBag` is a dynamic expression and it is available for all the pages. The data in `ViewBag` is the thing that changes as per we have assigned. If we are assigning `ViewBag.items=itemlist;` for a `View`, then it will be constant for that `View`. We can put as many data into `ViewBag` per page as we want like , for a single page, we can have

   ```
   ViewBag.items=itemlist;
   ViewBag.table=usertable;
   ```
2. You can maintain the information across the pages in MVC by passing the data as a parameter to the method which rendres the View on which we want to maintain the information as below:

   ```
   public ActionResult CreateEmployee(EmployeeModel emp)
   {
        //Add Employee to db
        ViewBag.employee=emp;
        RedirectToAction("MethodToCall","Controller");
   }
   ```

Thus the next page can have the employee information contained in the `ViewBag`

Alternatively, you can use `ViewData` as well.

3] State can be maintained using sessions, cookies etc